# email not sent in newsletter

Tags: magento-1.9, php, newsletter

i created a newsletter email template and schedule the time 3-july-2015 4:49 pm, but still the news letter subscription user not get the news letter mail .

Here i attached the newsletters subscription users and newsletter queue
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I made a module that solves this, and can be enabled and disabled from the backend.

Module configuration screenshot:-http://cl.ly/4na2

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/send-a-test-newsletter-to-an-email.html

Comment: thanks for your answer,but your answer is not closely match my question.

Comment: visit link:-http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/send-a-test-newsletter-to-an-email.html